# Not able to sign-in from an iframe which contains google analytics page

Tags: html, iframe, google-analytics

I wanted to use an iframe which displays some metrics that the google analytics is tracking for me.

I used it like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/analytics/" style="width: 1158px; height: 640px"></iframe>
```

The page gets displayed but I am not able to sign-in from the iframe when it is displayed in the browser. Is there anything more that should be added to this so that I could sign-in from my web page itself into the anaytics?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for security reasons, google does not allow access to sign-in pages from an iframe. The idea is that it would be more difficult for users to tell between legitimate usages connecting to the actual google site, and fake login harvesting sites.